# First instance when Clark Kent worked as something other than a journalist

Tags: dc, comics, superman

Clark Kent, in most of his appearances, works as journalist for the Daily Planet. As far as I can remember, he has always worked as a journalist in all of his incarnations except when he did different jobs in the movie *Man Of Steel* (2013) such as oil refinery worker, and as a worker at a restaurant.

What was the first instance when Clark Kent worked as something other than a journalist?

Here work means *"a job to earn money"*

Comment: https://www.looper.com/71623/jobs-people-dont-know-superman/ - Novelist, fireman, farmer, professional wrestler, King of Earth, etc etc. Too many to count. None of them stuck.

Comment: Earliest in life, or first in publication?

Comment: @Spencer - I suspect they're the same

Comment: @Valorum Maybe. But Clark (as Superboy) worked as a circus strongman for a while. _Superboy_ #2 , 1981

Comment: @Spencer, publication

Comment: @Spencer - You'll need to beat a [canon reference to his first job, published in 1950](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/276548/20774)

Comment: Technically he also worked at the Daily Star, but they retconned that because it was the name of a real newspaper

Comment: are we talking movies?  tv?  comics?  canon?  non-canon?  There could be a lot of different answers...

Comment: @user23298 - If you can find an instance from any of the above that pre-dates 1950, then have at it

Comment: I think that his first "job" was working at the family store.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt - Well, farming. But I doubt he was gainfully employed doing it.

Answer (score 11):

Superman's first *regular* employment (at the age of approximately 15) was as a busboy at the Cosmopolitan Restaurant in Metropolis, as seen in the [Adventure Comics #152](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Adventure_Comics_Vol_1_152) story '*Superboy Hunts for a Job*", published in May, 1950.

[image]

He did also briefly work as a freelance toy tester for *Moore's Toughwear Toys* at the age of twelve, earning the princely sum of $3 for his efforts in *[Adventure Comics #116](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Adventure_Comics_Vol_1_116)*, published in May, 1947.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dammit! I spent an hour searching for "Clark Kent working as a busboy", but I kept including Smallville in my search terms so no luck - I actually had seen that comic in the early 1960s and it stayed in my memory

Comment: @DannyMcG - Jeepers! I've found an example that's even earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Young Clark kent worked in his family's general store in Smallville - one must assume he was paid at least a small stipend.

[image]

Comment: With that lackadaisical work attitude I'm surprised he hasn't been fired already.

Comment: Purely for the record, the Kent Family Store doesn't make an appearance until *Adventure Comics Vol 1 #210* in March, 1955. By that point Superboy had already worked for the Daily Planet as a newsboy.

Answer (score 0):

I know that in one of the early tv shows, he worked as a tv news anchor rather than an investigative reporter. He sat at a desk reporting the news on tv. Still in the field of journalism, of course. I also read that he left The Daily Planet and hired by Morgan Edge as a tv reporter for WGBS (Galaxy Broadcasting System) in Issue 233 (1971)for a significant period in the comics right up until The Superman (1978) movie came out, I believe, and his Smallville girlfriend, Lana Lang was even his co-anchor for a little while!
[advertisement for Superman Issue 233 here](https://www.comiclink.com/img/comics/scans/RAD1BC5C2018919_14426.jpg)

[Superman 233 cover](https://superman.fandom.com/wiki/Bronze_Age?file=Kryptonite_Nevermore.jpg)

Comment: You could greatly improve this answer by editing it to name the specific TV show in which Clark worked as a TV news anchor, and any of the specific issues in the comics where he did so as well.